# Visual studio 2013 and Windows 8.1 .. Windows Phone Emulator wont launch,, HYper V issue

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, hypervisor

I have a windows 8.1 installation and visual studio 2013 with windows phone sdk but when i try to debug or launch an emulator it says "The Windows emulator could not start because the the Hyper V is not runnung which is probably because hardware assisted virtuaization isnt enabled".
Whilei have triple checked that from BIOS that virtualization is enabled and using coreinfo utility i have confirmed the presence of compatible system and HYPER Visor. 
Kindly help with this

Also i have the VS2013 update 1 installed

Comment: Are you running Windows 8.1 Pro?  That is the only version that will work with the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1)Copy paste this code in notepad

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

2) save it as .bat

3) run it as admin

4) restart and check whether HyperV is enabled or not